# Can i broadcast a particles.js background and interactions using node/sockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, particles.js

I want to broadcast a particles.js background using sockets that allows for multiple connections to interact simultaneously.I am broadcasting the particlesJS function as well as JSON configuration and mouse movements from each connection, but am having trouble getting the click/hover events to broadcast the particles interactions.
1) Server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('./server/routes')(app);

var server = app.listen(8000);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.on('mouse_activity', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.emit('all_mouse_activity', {session_id: socket.id, 
coords: data})
});

socket.on('generate', function(data){
    socket.broadcast.emit('particles',data)
})

socket.on('myClick', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('myClick', data);
});

})
```

2)HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="http://192.168.1.192:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"> . 
</script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
. 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"> . 
</script>
<title>Document</title>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.192:8000')

$(document).ready(function(){
    socket.emit('generate',particlesJS('particles-js',{
        "particles": {
            "number": {
            "value": 11,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
            },
            "color": {
            "value": "#ffffff"
            },
            "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
            }
            },
            "opacity": {
            "value": 0.64,
            "random": false,
            "anim": {
                "enable": true,
                "speed": 0.3248308849205381,
                "opacity_min": 0.13805312609122866,
                "sync": false
            }
            },
            "size": {
            "value": 114.42640803667955,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 17.053621458328248,
                "size_min": 8.932849335314796,
                "sync": false
            }
            },
            "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
            },
            "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 2.3,
            "direction": "top",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
            }
            }
        },
        "interactivity": {
            "detect_on": "canvas",
            "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "bubble"
            },
            "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "resize": true
            },
            "modes": {
            "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                "opacity": 1
                }
            },
            "bubble": {
                "distance": 85.26810729164123,
                "size": 93.3888794146547,
                "duration": 9.826134268846276,
                "opacity": 1,
                "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
                "distance": 592.8163649799819,
                "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
            }
            }
        },
        "retina_detect": true
        }))
})

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
    socket.emit('mouse_activity', {x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY})
});

socket.on('all_mouse_activity', function(data){
    if($('.pointer[session_id="'+data.session_id+'"]').length <= 0){
        $('body').append('<div class="pointer" 
session_id="'+data.session_id+'"></div>')
    }

    var $pointer = $('.pointer[session_id="'+data.session_id+'"]');

    $pointer.css('left', data.coords.x);
    $pointer.css('top', data.coords.y);
});

socket.on('particles', function(data){
    $('#bg').html(data)
})

$(document).on('click', function(event){
socket.emit('myClick', {id: event.target})
});

socket.on('myClick', function (data) {
$(data.id).trigger('click');
});



</script>
</head>
<body id="particles-js">
<script id="bg"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your server outputting data when it receives the 'mouse_activity' message?

Comment: Yes 'mouse_activity' is broadcasting each browser's mouse movements live.It seems 'click' and 'myClick' are not having any effect on the dom tho.